# Angry bird Physic impact/collision

Tags: physics, game-physics, physics-engine

How do I create a motion impact/collision like angry bird. When the object hit the box and wood, their interaction and the flow of the animation will to the right position. I need to learn from scratch how to build it. I need the basic of physic and concept

Example image:

[image: Example image]

So far, What i think so far is. Upon impact, I will apply

1. Law of Restitution

   object 1 velocity = e(ball velocity)
2. I will take the direction of the ball and make the  object 1 to rotation 90% against the ball.

   if ball ---> direction. my end result for object 1 will be 90 degree against it. so it will become

   |____| it will turn into this.
3. So far it seen right. But I am unsure how to interact with object 2. Do I repeat step and 2. Whereby I passed the velocity and direction to object 2. so it will rotation 90 degree again?

This is what I have gather so far. Any suggest that I am moving to right direction will be good.

For collision part. I intend to use AABB. and rotation AABB.

Comment: Google "how to build a physics engine"?

Comment: What you have so far doesn't seem quite right. If the ball hits an object perpendicularly at the top, it will rotate x degrees (bottom basically stays put), at the bottom -x degrees (top basically stays put), in the middle 0 degrees, just move backwards.

Comment: Improved formatting, see edit.

Comment: I would say, go with [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) instead of reinventing the wheel (unless your goal is really to reinvent the wheel in order to learn physics engines programming). Proper (though approximate) handling of colliding rigid objects requires knowledge about mechanics and constraint dynamics, iterative solvers, possibly sparse matrices, and so on.

Answer (score 7):

AngryBirds used `Box2D` physics when I opened About page inside game.
`Box2D` is open source physics engine.
Most physics engines are based on impulses. They sum impulses and re-calculate velocities.
The most complex and import part is what happens when collision occur.

Physic Engine detect all collisions and use `Solver` function. `Solver` is heart and sole of phsyics engine. `Solve` adds additional impulses to "solve" collision.

Solver usually has form of function that takes collision island (list of colliding objects: often 2 objects) and return force or impulse to be applied to each object.

Most modern engines are impulse based.

So most important part of physics engine to learn and understand is `Solver` function. But solver could be more complex entity then function.